# node.js / Write buffer to file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file, with size of 108 bytes.

I want to add to this file some text (buffer), let say `"Hello world"`.

So I wrote the next:

```
fs.open("./tryit.txt", 'w+', function (err, fd1) {
    var buffer = new Buffer("hello world");
    fs.write(fd1, buffer, 0, 11, 109, function (err, bytesWrite, buffer) {
        })
})
```

In order to write the file from position of `109`.

I see that it write it, but before the `hello world`, all the text of the file was replaced by the `NUL` character.

How can I do it? `append` is not an option, because in some cases I want to write to the middle of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is random access IO (read or write at a specific point in a file).

It's not provided in the default API but you may use an additional package like https://www.npmjs.org/package/random-access-file

Comment: Thank God you answered first. I was about to reccomend Winston. Guess I'm still asleep.

Answer (score -1):

From docs:

> 'w+' - Open file for reading and writing. The file is created (if it does not exist) or truncated (if it exists)

"truncated" means that file becomes empty once opened.

You need a different mode, `r+` for instance. `a` also might work, but not on Linux, according to docs.